# Testing Bandwidth in preparation of tele conferencing

Tags: qos, streaming

I am working for a company that is installing a video conferencing e-learning web application that is using a red5 media server.

The client is complaining that the performance is choppy/slow, and my boss is complaining that their network is probably at fault.

We gace decided that they should run some tests on their network and give us back some numbers related to bandwidth.

Could I have suggestions about which commands/tools to use to get good measurements from 1 computer to the red5 streaming server?

Thanks

### Update

I am now using iperf to get bandwidth for TCP and UDP using the command:

```
C:\Tools\iperf-3.0.11-win64>iperf3.exe -c IP_ADDRESS -p 5201
Connecting to host localhost, port 5201
[  4] local ::1 port 56453 connected to ::1 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  1.38 MBytes  11.5 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  1.12 MBytes  9.44 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   640 KBytes  5.24 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   768 KBytes  6.29 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   768 KBytes  6.29 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec   768 KBytes  6.29 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  1.12 MBytes  9.44 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec   896 KBytes  7.34 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  1.00 MBytes  8.39 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec   768 KBytes  6.30 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  9.12 MBytes  7.65 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  8.96 MBytes  7.52 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

Comment: I install VoIP solutions, and I use [http://startrinity.com/VoIP/SipTester/SipTester.aspx] (StarTrinity). Voice calls are not the same as videoconference but it can give you an idea how is your bandwith behaving on stressful conditions.

Comment: Question about product or resource recommendations are specifically off-topic.

Comment: Thanks jcbemu for the links. @maythesource.com, make sure you have qos setup for voip in your network infrastructure. http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/QoS

Comment: @ Ron Maupin Know any sites appropriate for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of what Red5 in particular is/how it uses the bandwidth, but with voice and videoconferencing, bandwidth itself is just half of the story. You need to check for jitter and delay, which are critical for that kind of applications. If jitter is high, you'll experience what you're describing: "choppy".

If you have Cisco routers at customer, you can use IP SLA[1] to test for video/voice, along with very detailed analysis of performance data. Measuring bandwidth is not enough.

[1]. http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/solutions/medianet/docs/IP_SLA_Video_Operation_Across_Platforms.pdf

Comment: Cisco device also support TTCP: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/dial-access/asynchronous-connections/10340-ttcp.html

Answer (score -2):

You can test you bandwidth width the good old speedtest via CLI : https://blog.nousefreak.be/blog/cli-speedtest